# Are Kaip or Kype tools still around(Forgive the spelling)

Tags: software-rec

I was looking for the name of an old plugin I used for video or photoshopping back in the day.  Wondering if it's still around a decade later.  I remember it being Kaip or Kype or something of that nature.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess you were referring to Kai's Power Tools, which haven't been maintained for quite a while.

Here's some random webpages about it and its history:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kai%27s_Power_Tools

http://graphicssoft.about.com/od/whathappenedto/p/kpt.htm